# Add and remove item dynamically in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add or remove dropdown items dynamically in jQuery? Below code is not working

```
$("#dropdownId").remove("<option value='12'>testing</option>");
$("#dropdownId").add("<option value='12'>testing</option>");
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a standard selector for the item you want to remove, rather than passing html markup:

```
$('#dropdownId option[value="12"]').remove();
// or
$('#dropdownId').remove('option[value="12"]');
```

(I'm assuming you don't have more than one option with the same value.)

The (approximate) opposite of [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("#dropdownId").append("<option value='12'>testing</option>");
```

Comment: To be more precise, `.append()` is the opposite of `.detach()` (which works similarly to `.remove()`, but still not identically).

Comment: remove() returns the node removed. It would be best to assign that to a variable and then append it since appending a string can possibly introduce bugs. Most importantly, the html nodes can and probably will change in the future.

Comment: @jlafay: No, in such case use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`.

Comment: @jlafay - I didn't worry about keeping a reference to the removed element because I doubt the requirement is to remove and then immediately re-add the same item. The question asked how to add _or_ remove, so I just covered each case more generally.

Comment: both remove and detach are not working for dynamic removal of items, I have tried like $('#offer_store option[value="'+ storIds + '"]').detach();  and also like  $('#offer_store').detach('option[value="'+ storIds + '"]');

Comment: Update your question to show your actual html, and what's in the `storIds` variable. It's hard to guess what's going wrong without seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

To add elements, use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('#dropdownId').append('<option value="12">testing</option>')
```

or [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('<option/>', { val: 12, text: 'testing' }).appendTo('#dropdownId');
```

To remove, use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) differently:

```
$('#dropdownId').find('option').filter(function ()
{
    return this.value === '12' && $(this).text() === 'testing';
}).remove();
```

---

As a general recommendation, you should really read the API docs for simple jQuery questions like these. If you had read [the documentation for `.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/), for instance, you'd see that it does not do what you thought.

Comment: Why not just use selector for choosing the option based on the value?

Comment: @Tadeck AIUI it's generally not as robust to select an element by its `value` attribute as it is to check the `.value` property. Basically, the age-old problem of properties vs attributes.

Comment: remove item is not working, I have tried like  $('#offer_store').find('option').filter(function ()
     {
         return this.value == storIds;
     }).remove();

Comment: try this `$('#dropdownId').find('option[value=' + storIds + ']').remove();`

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
$("#selectList option[value='2']").remove();
```

Add:

```
$('#selectList').append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` instead of `add` !

Answer (score 0):

add is not writing method.
use append() like,

```
$("#dropdownId").append("<option value='12'>testing</option>");
```

here's some information from jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/append/